# Backbone + Underscore: Can't find Template Variable. + Howto correctly access Modelattributes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I just started with Backbone and my goal is a simple slidecasting application. I have a REST Interface where

`/slidecasts`

gets me a list of all available presentations. the returned json looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "p75-barth.pdf", 
        "nr": 1, 
        "slideLinks": [
            "slides/0", 
            "slides/1",                
        ]
}]
```

If I want to access a single presentation and get for example the first slide I can simply do:

```
slidecasts/1/slides
```

which returns:

```
[
    {
        "content": null, 
        "imageLinks": [
            "images/1"
        ], 
        "nr": 0, 
        "title": null
    }
]
```

I want to represent a Presentation and Slides as Backbone Models. I also want to have a Backbone View which in the end simply shows a slide-image, the title, some notes and a forward/backward button.

this is my code so far:

```
$(function (){

    initModel();
    initCollection();
    initView();

    var testSlidecast = new Slidecast();
    testSlidecast.id=1;

    testSlide = new Slide();
    testSlide.id = 5;

    testSlidecast.Slide = testSlide;

    var slideView = new SlideView(({model: testSlidecast}));

})

function initView(){
    SlideView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#presentation"),
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
            alert("asd")
        },
        render: function(){
            var variables = { presentation_name: "This is a Test-Slide-Name" };
            var template = _.template( $("#slide_template").html(), {} );
            this.el.html( template );
        }
    });
}

function initModel(){
    Slide = Backbone.Model.extend({
    });
}

function initCollection(){
    Slidecast = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: Slide,
      url: function(){
        return 'slidecasts/' + this.id + '/slides'
      }
    });
}
```

This works for a Collection but I don't really know how I can get the Infos for a single Slide from there. Is something like slidecast.slide("0")  possible?

I also have some problems regarding the templating for my view:

My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js" > </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" > </script>
    <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js" > </script>
    <script src="bscript.js" > </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="presentation"> </div>

    <script type="text/template" id="slide_template">
            <label>Presentation <%= presentation_name %>  </label>
            <img src="" id="slide_pic" />
            <input type="text" id="slide_content" value="asd" />
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I keep getting the error that the variable name i want to pass to my template *presentation_name* is not defined although I have defined the variable in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables in the scope of the template must be explicitly passed. The template does not get access to variables in the view's scope automatically. Instead of:

```
var template = _.template( $("#slide_template").html(), {} );
```

Try

```
var template = _.template( $("#slide_template").html(), variables);
```

Comment: thanks. do you have a comment  on how i organised the collection/models? how can i easily access the property of a single slide?

Comment: Drop all the `initX` functions and define your Backbone constructors top-level. Don't set an `id` on your Collection, only the Model, and it's better to pass `id` as part of the attributes hash when you create a new `Model` instance. Views must return `this` from the `render` function. Do populate a collection with models, pass an array of models as the first argument to the constructor. In general in backbone you almost never directly set object properties. It's always with the constructor or get/set.

Comment: why shouldn't i set an id on the collection? in my case the collection-id marks the id of the presentation and the model id the slide number.  they both have to be defined seperately?!

Comment: Hmm, yeah in your case the way you are using your collection it can have an ID. Usually collections in a normal REST-style API don't have IDs (/users, /posts, /pages, etc). Usually models have IDs (/user/42), but it can get ambiguous depending on what you consider a resource.